# Saving VLC stream to mp4 Configuration

Tags: c#, video, mp4, vlc, libvlc

I am using a VLC component in my WPF application with C# and I adding this option to VLC:

```
 Options = @":sout=#duplicate{dst=display,dst=std{access=file,mux=ts,dst=" + outputFileName + "}}";
```

With this option I am able to save the stream to mpg.

I want to save the stream to mp4 and I tried:

```
Options = @":sout=#duplicate{dst=display,dst=std{access=file,mux=mp4,dst=" + outputFileName + "}}";
```

and

```
Options = @":sout=#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=800, scale=1,acodec=flac,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:std{access=file,mux=ogg,dst=" + outputFileName + "}}";
```

but this two option the VLC does not work at all.

What option should I used for sout if I want to save to mp4

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

my case:

```
string s = "rtsp://address:554/stream";
VlcControl vlcControl = null;
Thread thread = new Thread(() => { vlcControl = new VlcControl(); });
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
thread.Join();
vlcControl.MediaPlayer.VlcLibDirectoryNeeded += OnVlcControlNeedsLibDirectory;
vlcControl.MediaPlayer.EndInit(); //Important
prms = prms.Concat(new String[] { ":sout=#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,acodec=none,vb=128,deinterlace}:std{access=file,mux=mp4,dst=" + pathNameFile + "_" + i++ + ".mp4}"}).ToArray();
vlcControl.MediaPlayer.Play(new Uri(s), prms);
```

Comment: Can you also add an explanation?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10180268)

Comment: @JamieR: this could answer the question, because he uses another parameter string. But an explanation would be very helpful.

Comment: vlc.dotnet last version, have comment method 'EndInit()' in function 'Play()'. so when call 'play()' nothing happens (only wpf), therefore need 'vlcControl.MediaPlayer.EndInit();'. Sorry for my eng..